# Calling GetListItems - no data being returned

Tags: development, spservices

I am calling GetListItems via c# code to return all items in a SharePoint list. Here is a snippet of code:

```
private string listName = "Test2";
private string viewName = string.Empty;
private string rowLimit = "150";


SPListService.Lists listService = new SPListService.Lists();
listService.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
listService.Url = "http://test.testsite.sp/MyTest/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx";

System.Xml.XmlDocument xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
System.Xml.XmlElement query = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Query");
System.Xml.XmlElement viewFields = xmlDoc.CreateElement("ViewFields");
System.Xml.XmlElement queryOptions = xmlDoc.CreateElement("QueryOptions");

query.InnerXml = "";
viewFields.InnerXml = "<FieldRef Name=\"Title\" />";
queryOptions.InnerXml = "<IncludeMandatoryColumns>FALSE</IncludeMandatoryColumns><DateInUtc>TRUE</DateInUtc> ";

System.Xml.XmlNode nodeListItems = listService.GetListItems
(listName, viewName, query, viewFields, rowLimit, queryOptions, null);
```

I do not get an error but no results are returned.

```
InnerXml    "\n<rs:data ItemCount=\"0\" xmlns:rs=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset\">\n</rs:data>\n"
```

I have searched various sites (including this one) and nothing seems to work. 
:-(

I have also tried to pass in GUIDs for the viewName and listName, but makes no difference.

Has anyone else been through this before?

I am starting to wonder whether it's the permissions on the SharePoint side that could be causing this.

Thank you

Comment: Did you copy this code directly from your source?  The line `queryOptions.InnerXml = "IncludeMandatoryColumns>FALSE</IncludeMandatoryColumns><DateInUtc>TRUE</DateInUtc> ";` is missing a `<` before `IncludeMandatoryColumns`

Comment: Hi Jeff, thanks for pointing this out, I have included the `<` before `IncludeMandatoryColumns` in the actual code. I will amend this in the post now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a "Query". Try:

```
query.InnerXML = "<Where><IsNotNull><FieldRef Name='ID'/></IsNotNull></Where>";
```

This should return "All Items". If you want to filter it, you'll need to learn the specific CAML query needed for that.

Comment: Hi Chad, thanks for you'r reply. Unfortunately that didn't change anything, I'm still not getting anything back.

Comment: Interesting, ok I looked at my code and noticed a couple other things. Instead of empty string try null for the view name. Instead of list name, try list ID (internal GUID), you can get this from the List Settings page in the url.  Remove the extra space at the end of QueryOptions. Everything else looks good unless my eyes aren't catching a typo.

Comment: Forgot one other thing. Try query.InnerXml = "<IsNotNull><FieldRef Name='ID'/></IsNotNull>";  (basically remove the Where portion).